# Visitor stamp with BRP number on it?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, borders, passport-stamps

I entered the UK using my passport and BRP card an received a visitor stamp (6 months) with my BRP number written on it. Should I be worried? Should I contact anyone?

My BRP is valid for 2 more years.

Comment: What exactly are you considering being worried *about*?

Comment: For starters, I am not a visitor. I live here. Why would I receive a visitor stamp?

Comment: Does the stamp contain the wording "Leave to enter for six months: Employment and recourse to public funds prohibited." on top of the rectangular box with rounded corners, or just the rectangular box?

Comment: @B.Liu It does! Although a bit faded.

Comment: What did the Immigration Officer say when you asked them why they stamped your entry like this?

Comment: I did not ask as I did not notice until I was passed the border. They also asked me no questions at all! Just wrote my BRP number on top of the stamp and that’s it.  Should I call them for clarification?

Answer (score 5):

I just called them and was informed that as long as the BRP number is on top of the stamped part then everything is okay.

Comment: Thanks for your own answer, this will be helpful for people in the same situation.